# What does "multiple base classes" mean?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

The "*Objective-C for Java Programmers, Part 1*" intro by *David Chisnall* states that

> Because you can have multiple base classes, Objective-C introduces the
>   id type to represent a pointer to some kind of object. You can
>   implicitly cast between any object type and id.

To the best of my understanding, Objective-C is **single-inheritance** (just like Java, but unlike C++).

So what does "multiple base classes" mean (in this context)?

Comment: Are they only speaking of single-inheritance along multiple ancestors in a class hierarchy?

Comment: That's exactly what I initially thought, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to know this and sure enough @bbum just clarified what this means. Objective-C *is* different from both Java and C++. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you can define your own root or "base" class.

```
@interface MyRootClass
@end
```

Note that it does not inherit from `NSObject`.

In practice, this is never done because said class can't really be used inter-operably with the rest of the system APIs because they all expect `NSObject` inherited behavior.

That isn't really the motivation behind the `id` type, though.   The `id` type means, quite literally, *this object reference can be an instance of any class*.

That there may be multiple base classes is entirely orthogonal.

No, implementing the `NSObject` `@protocol` isn't really good enough.

Comment: Historically (pre-NeXT), objects didn't have separate types, like NSObject* or NSString*; they were all simply `id` (which was a kind of pointer). Even though you can now declare objects as pointers to specific classes, the old use of `id` as a catchall remains.

Comment: The pre-1994 NeXT class hierarchy was rooted at Object and everything almost exclusively inherited from that.  IIRC, the same was true of StepStone's object hierarchies.  There was always a strong notion of One Root Class to Rule Them All in commonly available ObjC environments.

Comment: Were the pre-1994 NeXT classes basically like the StepStone ones, or more similar to the later NS* ones?

Comment: The classes *were* largely the StepStone ones, with some modifications here and there. Object, List, and Hash were all provided by the runtime (and the remnants of List and Object are still in the modern runtime).  Where the two diverged was in the AppKit (NeXT) and the various ICPaks (StepStone).   Been a long time, though, and details are fuzzy.